# Bootstrap: Inline form with headings

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to produce an inline-form that is editable within Bootstrap. I can't seem to get controls to layout when using fluid rows and I need some headings at the top and can't figure out how to get it to line up right.

I've forked a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/IPWright83/CdNef/243/) that illustrates the idea. As you can see the controls overlap which isn't great. Originally before an inline-form I was trying to use a table but discovered that the various input controls really weren't happy in it.

```
<div id="wrapper" class="container-fluid">
<div class="row-fluid">
<form id="frmOptions" method="post" class="well form-inline span12">

     <div class="row-fluid">   
        <div id="formLeft" class="span3">
          <div class="control-group">
            <label for="select1" class="control-label">Option 1:</label>
            <div class="controls">
                <select id="select1">
                    <option>Something</option>
                </select>
                    <select id="select1">
                    <option>Something</option>
                </select>
            </div>      
          </div>
        </div>

        <div id="formCenter" class="span3">
          <div class="control-group">
            <label for="select2" class="control-label">Option 2:</label>
            <div class="controls">
                <select id="select2">
                    <option>Something</option>
                </select>
                 <select id="select2">
                    <option>Something</option>
                </select>
            </div>      
          </div>    
        </div>

        <div id="formRight" class="span3">
          <div class="control-group">
            <label for="select3" class="control-label">Option 3:</label>
            <div class="controls">
                <select id="select3">
                    <option>Something</option>
                </select>
                <select id="select3">
                    <option>Something</option>
                </select>
            </div>      
          </div>    
    </div>   

</form>
</div>
</div>
```

Does anyone have any suggestions how to fix this? I'm up for using bootstrap selectors http://silviomoreto.github.com/bootstrap-select/ if neccessary but I've not tried them yet.

Comment: Grid sizing Use .span1 to .span12 for inputs that match the same sizes of the grid columns. Your column is of span3 using the span12 for that is a wrong way to do the sizing stuff . http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/base-css.html#forms

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add the `span12` class to your `<select>` elements: http://jsfiddle.net/kaleb/CdNef/244/

That fixes the overlap. I hope this is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following to make your select boxes arranged as desired :

JSfiddle [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/shail/CdNef/245/show/)

```
 .form-inline select {
 margin-bottom:10px;
 }
 @media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 979px) {
#frmOptions select {
     width:100%;
    }
    }
 @media (max-width: 767px) {
#frmOptions select {
     width:100%
    }
   }
 @media (max-width: 480px) {
  #frmOptions select {
     width:100%;
    }
  }
```

BTW I think you could have created the form this way as well , might help ya later

[form jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/shail/sGgKE/)

Comment: Adding the `span12` class in a `.fluid-row` gives a width of 100%.

Comment: @kzh Well I have my ways .. btw wats the issue in writing the way I did